# SVN: Checking out a large project over slow connection

Tags: svn, version-control

I am new to SVN. I want to check out a very large project over a slow connection which takes ages to download. I have zipped versions of project on both remote server and my local which are identical. Is there an easy and quick way to sync my local project with remote server without a full checkout?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a checkout on the server and then copy it to the local machine on an USB stick or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

A `svn checkout` on your local unzipped directory that contains the project files should work without subversion fetching all the stuff from the server.

SVN should be intelligent enough to recognize files that are already identical - I know for a fact that Windows client TortoiseSVN is, and seeing as it's using the native `svn` binaries under the hood, I assume this is a native feature.

Of course, you need to get the paths exactly right so the structures match; and be sure to make backups first - **any local changes not in the repository *will* be overwritten this way!**